# Which all tables get updated during a content a saved in drupal

Tags: drupal-6

Hi
can you people tell me which all tables are get updated during a content(example page content type ) in drupal
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

node, node_access, node_comment_statics and node_revisions are node related tables that get updated during page creation.